# How to move objects /images in RMarkdown?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I discovered this RMarkdown document in this [video](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2018/parameterized-r-markdown-reports-with-rstudio-connect/) and I am wondering how the creator of this Markdown document was able to shift the pear images to the left while maintaining the text on the left side of the document. From my understanding this requires understanding some HTML to move these objects. I know a little know understand this but not enough to implement this. Would anyone have any ideas on how to do something like this?

The main reason I want to do something like this is because I want to create a dashboard style RMarkdown document (not using Flexdashboard or Shiny, strictly Markdown)

**Desired Output of a document: In short, how did the author get the image of this peach on the left side of this document?**

[image]

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html

Comment: This is more of a CSS issue.  You might want to look at flexbox or a similar approach for grid layouts.

Comment: There are a couple of templates that could possibly get this result, could of used a word doc for the template or just HTML/CSS, do you have any sample code you have tried?

Comment: @DanielJachetta thanks, I do no have any sample code at the moment. I would in any other case but I do not know how to write any html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing that was done in the Code for the video was:

```
<div style="float:right; margin-left: 40px;">
</div>
```

Which inside the div had the image that was floated right in HTML

I tried to give you a basic replica of your image. This is why I love Rmarkdown, it is so diverse and powerful. I am not sure exactly what graphing library is used, I used `plotly` and it was just `output: html_document` file.

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

<div style="float:right; margin-left: 40px;">
```{r out.width="600px",echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(knitr)
include_graphics('https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.    com-red-appleapplemalus-domesticafruitdeliciousred-apple-1701527164    92043huf.png')
```
</div>

# scientific
([**scientific**]() |
[**scientific**]() |
[**scientific**]())

*Date:* 01-01-1999

**name:** Tim Jackson <br>
**company:** Investing Inc. <br>
**example:** June 2021 report

This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This     is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a     paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a     paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a     paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a     paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.

```{r out.width="300px",echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}

library(plotly)

trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)
x <- c(1:100)

data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x) 
fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0',mode = 'lines') 

```
````

Comment: This is awesome and I was able to reproduce the example as well, thank you tons!